# Python Mock Factory Sub Classes and Methods

Tags: python, mocking, python-unittest

I need to mock `MyClassFactory` which returns a MyClass object. This object has a method `getNum` I need to mock as well. I'm not sure how to do this as the factory no longer returns `MyClass`, but instead `<MagicMock name='mock().create()'...>`.

```
import unittest
from mock import MagicMock, Mock, patch

class MyClass:
    def getNum(self):
        return 10

class MyClassFactory:
    def create(self):
        return MyClass()

class Runner:
    def foo(self):
        myClassFactory = MyClassFactory()
        myClass = myClassFactory.create()

        num = myClass.getNum()

        if num == 10:
            print("foo successful")
        else:
            print("foo fail, num={}".format(num))

class TestRoute(unittest.TestCase):
    # Attempt at patching the methods
    @patch("__main__.MyClassFactory", create=True, new=MagicMock())
    @patch("__main__.MyClass", create=True, new=MagicMock())
    @patch("__main__.MyClass.getNum", create=True, new=MagicMock(return_value=11))
    def test_foo_fail(self):
        runner = Runner()
        runner.foo()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

Actual Output:

```
foo fail, num=<MagicMock name='mock().create().getNum()' id='140554774258128'>
```

Desired Output:

```
foo fail, num=11
```

This `<MagicMock name='mock().create().getNum()'...>` is not what I want. I attempted to use `return_value=11` for the mocked method but it's not being called.

TLDR: I have a factory which I need to mock. It returns a class. That class has a method I also need to mock the return_value which I can't do. Basically I want to turn `mock().create().getNum()` into `11`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What's happening is your first patch

```
@patch("__main__.MyClass", create=True, new=MagicMock())
```

replaces the class instantiation of "**main**.MyClass" with MagicMock(). So the next patch:

```
@patch("__main__.MyClass.getNum", create=True, new=MagicMock(return_value=11))
```

ends up trying to call the method of a MagicMock() object rather than the original **main**.MyClass, which results in the output you're seeing.

[You need to attach mocks as attributes and set up each child mock.](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#attaching-mocks-as-attributes) Rather than patching before the test, try patching before the call to foo.

```
import unittest
from mock import MagicMock, Mock, patch

class MyClass:
    def getNum(self):
        return 10

class MyClassFactory:
    def create(self):
        return MyClass()

class Runner:
    def foo(self):
        myClassFactory = MyClassFactory()
        myClass = myClassFactory.create()
        print(myClassFactory)
        print(myClass)
        num = myClass.getNum()
        if num == 10:
            print("foo successful")
        else:
            print("foo fail, num={}".format(num))

class TestRoute(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_foo_fail(self):
        getNumMock = MagicMock(return_value = 20)

        myClassMock = MagicMock()
        myClassMock.getNum = getNumMock

        createMock = MagicMock(return_value = myClassMock)

        myClassFactoryMock = MagicMock()

        createMock.attach_mock(getNumMock, "getNum")
        myClassFactoryMock.attach_mock(createMock, "create")

        with patch('__main__.MyClassFactory', create=True, return_value=myClassFactoryMock):
            runner = Runner()
            runner.foo()
if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```